# Always show submenu vertically under parent

Tags: css, menu

I have been trying various tries into css, I want the submenu to appair vertical when clicking on the parent..

i use this template purchased: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_55042/

when clicking on the "Services" tab, I want the "submenu" is displayed vertically and always show under the parent

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.